# Flutter - run MATLAB function on mobile app (primary Android)

Tags: matlab, flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform

Is there a way to run a **MATLAB** function in **Flutter/Dart**?

Or, maybe **Flutter** has some library for advanced mathematical problems?

If not, can you recommend any cross platform mobile device technology, that will allow me to run **MATLAB** in code and get the results?

Working examples are much appreciated!

Comment: The quick answer is no, there aren't any MATLAB packages out there and there aren't likely to be any any time soon. The more complex answer is that MATLAB is a complete proprietary engine that AFAIK can't be embedded into an unrelated runtime, but since there is a MATLAB mobile app, perhaps there is an API that will enable you to communicate with a pre-existing engine. Or perhaps you can compile the MATLAB engine in C and create a mobile package from that, but that sits squarely in "here there be monsters" territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile MATLAB/Simulink code [into C code](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/generate-c-code-from-matlab-code-1.html), which you can then integrate into your flutter app [using dart:ffi](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop). While this may be tricky to set up first (be sure to follow the instructions from the flutter documentation, it's pretty good), it certainly works and I've done it before (only the flutter integration, not the Matlab to C part). Once it's set up, it's relatively easy to maintain. As you may have to write C/C++ wrappers for the generated C code some C knowledge may be helpful, but I don't think it's not worth trying.